# undefined reference to main in code blocks

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks, undefined-reference

A bit of the backstory: I first used Eclipse but it had trouble resolving namespace std so I switched to code::blocks and now I'm having this problem.

Everything went through debugging just fine except for one error: In function '_start': undefined reference to 'main' (.text+0x20). However, I have the main() defined and there's nothing fancy in it.

code::blocks version: 13.12
compiler: GNU gcc, have the g++ follow c++11

Thanks in advance.

There's nothing special in the main function

```
//: "main.cpp"
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;
    bar bar_;
    foo foo_;
    num = calc(bar_, foo_);
    cout << num << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the Build Log:

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/test obj/Debug/bar.o obj/Debug/foo.o   
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: Have you defined `main()`?

Comment: If only there was a way for us to see the code in question. Wouldn't that be a useful feature? :-)

Comment: You've shown us linking, what did you compile the objects with!

Comment: Are you asking about the compiler? It's gcc as said in the question.

Comment: have you tried using same compiler for the file containing main ? (ofcourse you have to replace **cout** with any **printf** family function e.g `printf("%d \n",num);` ) use `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: What's the name of the file in which you have your main() function? Is it in either foo.cpp or bar.cpp?

Comment: If `main()` is defined in main.cpp, shouldn't you also include *its* .o file in your `g++` call?

Answer (score 2):

1. `cout << << num << endl;` is invalid (note the two repeated `<<`). This means your `main.cpp` shouldn't even compile.
2. In your linking command, you're not linking `main.o` (the compiled object file for `main.cpp`). You're linking `foo.o` and `bar.o`, but you're missing `main.o`.

How you need to fix this:

1. Fix your code in `main.cpp`
2. Compile `main.cpp` to get the object file `main.o`
3. Link *all* the object files together.

Comment: The first one was a typo, fixed
for 2 and 3, I directly used 'build' in code::blocks, how come it didn't link 'main.o'?

Comment: @Siphenx: for future reference, you should include your *exact* code in your questions (not a retype, but a copy 'n' paste). It's part of providing a good [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is `main.cpp` part of your project? It's been years since I've used Code::Blocks, so I'm not much help there.

Comment: Yes, it's part of a small project.
Also, regarding copy n paste code, is there a way to make an entire 
block a code at once rather than indent every line manually?

Comment: When you're typing a question/answer, there's a button that looks like this: **`{}`**. If you select your code and click that button, it will automatically add 4 spaces to the beginning of every line so it will be formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm..

As per code block website, when such error occure,

**"Dont look at Build Message tab, look at Build log tab"**

In my case:
it was showing one .so file which is missing in linker.

Here is quick solution:

Setting>>compiler>>Linker Setting tab>>add path to .so file (which was pointed in build log)

Just ensure that the .so to add is really exist on your system.

Hope this helps.Cheers.